# Multiplication map of an elliptic curve is surjective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E:y^2z=x^3+Axz^2+Bz^3$ be an elliptic curve over a field $K$. Considering the usual abelian group $(E, +)$, I'm trying to prove the following for $m\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$:

> The multiplication map $[m]:E(\overline{K})\to E(\overline{K})$ given by $P\mapsto mP=P+...+P$ is surjective.

I already know how to prove the following:

($1$) The addition map $+:E(\overline{K})\times E(\overline{K})\to E(\overline{K})$ is a morphism of projective varieties.

($2$) $[m]$ is not constant.

Here is my attempt to prove surjectivity:

[I'll say "projective variety" meaning *irreducible* projective variety implicitly]

> *Proof:* By (1), $+:E(\overline{K})\times E(\overline{K})\to E(\overline{K})$ is a morphism of projective varieties, so $[2]= id+id$ is a morphism and so is $[m]=id+[m-1]$ by induction. Since morphisms of projective varieties map closed subsets to closed subsets (and are also continuous), $Im([m])$ is a subvariety of $E(\overline{K})$. Since $\dim E(\overline{K})=1$, we get:
>
> $$Im([m])\subsetneq E(\overline{K})\Rightarrow\dim Im([m])=0\Rightarrow Im([m]) \text{ is a point }$$
>
> By (2), we know $Im([m])$ cannot be a point, so $Im([m])=E(\overline{K})$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: You should also argue that it can't be a finite union of closed points (a closed subset of a connected curve is a finite union of points).

Comment: Otherwise you  can show it directly without using abstract properties of varieties :
Look at the affine curve $E: y^2 = x^3+Ax+B$. For any $(c,d) \in E$
let $(u(x,y),v(x,y)) = [m](x,y)+(c,d)$ and $F = K(A,B,c,d)$. Let $y =(x^3+Ax+B)^{1/2}$ algebraic over $F(x)$. Then $u(x,y) \in F(x,y)$ and  $u(x,y)u(x,-y)$ is fixed by the automorphism of $F(x,y)$ sending $y \to -y$, ie. $u(x,y)u(x,-y)= U(x) \in F(x)$. Since it is non-constant rational function which sends $\infty \to \infty$, it has a root.

Comment: @oxeimon, but the image of an irreducible set via a continuous function is also irreducible, right? In this case, if $Im([m])=\{P_1,...,P_k\}$ with $k>1$, then $[m]^{-1}(P_1),...,[m]^{-1}(P_k)$ are all disjoint, closed subsets of $E(\overline{K})$ and: $$E(\overline{K})=[m]^{-1}(P_1)\cup...\cup[m]^{-1}(P_k)$$ (absurd, since $E(\overline{K})$ is irreducible)

Comment: @reuns, I tried something like you said, but I was insecure: in order to apply the usual addition formula for $[m](x,y)$ for example, we have to assume the hypothesis of $(x, y), [2](x, y), ..., [m](x,y)$ being all affine points, right? But when we play around with $x,y$ isn't it possible to mess it up?

Comment: @AguirreK Yes that's right. I just thought it should be mentioned, assuming you were trying to be as precise as possible.

Comment: @AguirreK Here $(x,y)  \mapsto [2](x,y)$ is an element of the function field $\overline{K}(E)$. I meant $[m](x,y)+(c,d)$ with $+$ the addition in $\mathbb{Q}^2$ not in the curve. If instead you take $+$ the addition in the curve then you want $x_P\in \mathbb{Q} \cup \{\infty\}$ such that $u(x_P,y(x_P)) = \infty$, which is ensured by $U$ being non-constant. More generally on a variety of dimension $1$, any non-constant rational map has such a behavior.